# Is it possible to insert images directly from the server?

Tags: plugins, images, media-library

I've uploaded images directly to my WordPress server through FTP. I want to add these images to a post, so right now I'm using the [Add from Server](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-from-server/) plugin that allows me to browse images on the server and add them to the media library. The only thing I don't like about this is that adding an image to the media library generates two smaller versions of the image that are used for thumbnails. Is it not possible to completely bypass the media library and add images directly from the server?

Comment: Can't you just insert via URL?

Comment: @bungeshea Yes, but that gets tedious after a while, especially when you've organized your folders into directories and you don't know the exact structure and have to look it up. I'd prefer a solution that involves a file chooser.

Comment: Would simply disabling the generation of additional image sizes work?

Comment: @bungeshea Hmm, I think that would be fine. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: [See my answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77038/19726)

Comment: Also, I would like to say that adding images *to the media library* from URL is a feature that I would like to see in later versions of WordPress

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the best option here would be to disable the generation of additional image sizes on adding an image to the media library. Doing so is fairly straight-forward:

Visit the *Settings > Media* page of your WordPress dashboard. Under the *Image Sizes* section, change all of the values to 0.

[image: Media Settimgs]

Save the changes. This will stop WordPress generating thumbnails, medium, and large sizes of every image you upload.

You will also notice that when you go to insert an image, the "Size" dropdown box is missing.

Comment: Thanks, this works well. Although I wish WordPress would let me add media directly from the server without me having to modify their settings and add additional plugins.

Comment: I know what you mean. In WordPress 3.6 the media library will be totally revamped … perhaps someone could submit a [trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org) or an [idea](http://wordpress.org/extend/ideas) with this request?

Comment: Do you like a media library in backend of wordpress for the images of your folder, there you fill via ftp?